# New user does not work as expected

Tags: usb, mount

I've bought a RPi4 and want to make it work. Since I do not want to login as the 'pi' user, I created a new one as described here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/security.md:

```
 $ sudo adduser <new user name>
 $ sudo usermod -a -G adm,dialout,cdrom,sudo,audio,video,plugdev,games,users,input,netdev,gpio,i2c,spi <new user name>
```

The new user can see the drives using commands:

```
$ l /dev/s*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  8,  0 Mar 23 13:42 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  8,  1 Mar 23 13:42 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  8, 16 Mar 23 13:42 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  8, 17 Mar 23 13:42 /dev/sdb1
$ lsblk -o NAME,LABEL
NAME        LABEL
sda
└─sda1      USB20FD
sdb
└─sdb1
```

But I want to able to mount them via GUI. 'pi' user can do that. Mine cannot.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured that out. The problem was in ***autologin***. My machine used it and logged in as 'pi'. It locked the drives and did not let other users access them. I disabled this feature and now my user can mount the drives as I wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `File Manager` `Preferences` `Volume Management` there are options to set this.

This (IMO extremely annoying "feature" AKA bug) seems to be enabled for user pi.

You may need to enable this for other users. (I only access this to turn it off.)

Comment: Thanks. It's enabled by default for everyone. It's, actually, useful without autologin as I do not need to do anything special to work with my drives. So, I'm keeping it :-)